# Facebook soical plugin for comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I planning to do following things with Facebook's **social comment plugin**?

1. If someone gives a improper comment can I delete it? I meaning the owner of website who has integrated Facebook's plugin
2. Can I fetch all a comments /reply/likes/number of likes etc using a soma API so that i can process that data for my use?
3. Is Facebook's social comment plugin free?

Comment: Made me angry to read.. No formatting, no care for typing, way too many questions in one and a piece of source code that says: "Please do my work for me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to setup the open graph tags correctly, specifically the fb:admin tag.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
2. You cannot retrieve all comments associated to any particular app id that you control (meaning for example all of the FB comments for your website).  You can however retrieve all of the comments for any particular url.  An example would be: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}.  Read the docs for more info.
3. Yes it's free
4. Please clarify part 4 of your question.

Comment: you're better off not answering questions like this.